# AWs Neptune new Database endpoints Status stuck on 'Creating'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune

I am new to Neptune with no previous experience on it. My team wants to start using graph databases so asked me to set up a Neptune DB.
Following the AWs-provided guides step by step, I managed to get the Neptune Cluster created (Status shows available) but the Reader and Writer endpoints are stuck at `status = 'Creating'` for almost 2 days now.
Is this normal to take so long?
I tried doing this in two seperate Regions as well, thinking it might not be working correctly in Cape Town Region (af-south-1), but get the same scenario if I do it in Ireland Region.
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello - that does sound strange. Did you create the clusters from the console or using a Cloud Formation script, or some other way? If you are able to open a support case with information about the account and the cluster we can definitely take a look at why things are stuck. This is definitely not expected. Please excuse the really basic question, but if you refresh the view in the AWS Console web page does it still show "Creating"? - Just to rule out some sort of issue with the web page and not the cluster creation. Does a curl to `https://cluster-name:8182/status`  get anything back?

Comment: Any final answer to this? I am also stuck with the same thing. curl says could not resolve host. But console UI says cluster is Available but endpoints are Creating forever

Answer (score 0):

We would need to look at your cluster specifically to know what is going on. That would mean sharing your cluster and account details with us. The best path ahead would be to open a support case or maybe post via re:Post where official representatives from the team can get in touch with you to get your cluster details.

If you are unable to get help, please do report. We'll find alternate ways to exchange your cluster info securely to get someone to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well when creating the cluster with Terraform. My issue was that I created a `aws_neptune_cluster`, without a `aws_neptune_cluster_instance` which is necessary for endpoints to create.

The cluster resource in itself does not seem to include instances, hence the cluster instance resources to which you can set instance class as well as the number of instances. This is comparable in broader terms to a cluster control plane (neptune cluster), with its nodes (neptune cluster instance).